# Update android app from apk file. Hybrid app

Tags: android, angularjs, apk, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently developing a hybrid app in html, css, angular and ionic, that in the future needs some update functionality.

The iOS app is installed from ipa file, and when in want to update it, i just open/link to a manifest.plist, and the app is downloaded and updated.

But i can't make this to work with Android.
The app is installed from an apk-file. I would like to somehow download and install the updated apk-file so i dont need to remove the old app first.

Is there some way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload your new app as the same app as previous version except you need to increment the version number in manifest xml.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:versionCode="1"

. . .

</manifest>
```

You will need following:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:versionCode="2"

. . .

</manifest>
```

Comment: That was way more easy than expected! ...but just what i needed! now it works.. thank you!